# Generate SQL server Health Report

Tags: sql-server-2005

Are there any Query/Script to generate SQL serevr 2005 Health report , So i can send them to   client on regularly basis.
or can u tell me which type of report i can generate to send to client?

Thanks

Comment: What type of information are you expecting to see in the health report? Are you expecting information like index fragmentation, table sizes, RAM/CPU/IO usage? You might need to be a little more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use SQLDiag which the output can be used in conjunction with SQL Nexus:

http://www.codeplex.com/sqlnexus

This is part of what they do in a SQLRAP, only they use PSSDiag which is similar to SQLDiag.  You can also use the PAL Tool to generate reports from Performance Counter Log files:

http://www.codeplex.com/PAL

There are also some really good third party tools on the market from Quest, Red-Gate, Idera, Apex, and others (SQLSentry) that can be used for generating reports.  Additionally for free you can grab the SQL Health and History Tool (SQLH2) and reports from Codeplex if you want to install it:

http://www.codeplex.com/sqlh2